# Ionic app with approx. 2000 png icons that should be persistent on device

Tags: caching, ionic-framework, persistent-storage, preloading

For performance reason I want those pngs stored on the device upon download, resp. start of app. I am considering to use a stylesheet with each png used like

```
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYA.....==");
```

This css-file will be aprrox 2MB large and load with the index.html.

Is this idea feasible or should I use another approach? e.g. storing the base64 code as blobs in a sqlite db?

Comment: At what point do you download and how are these images used in the application ?

Comment: Staring the app should make dem persistent. They will be used in lists and in an autocomplete suggestion template.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Cordova's file APIs to store the files on disk.  Typically you'll want to store them in the application's data directory.

See the ngcordova documentation [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).  The writeFile method should work to store a base64 representation of the image.